# Apache archiva returns http error 503

Tags: jetty, 503-error

I am using apache Archiva v. 2.2.0 under Windows Server 2012 R2. With Java version 1.8.0_60 everything worked fine. After updating to 1.8.0_101_b13  I am getting an error message when going to archiva url:
HTTP ERROR: 503 . Problem accessing /. Reason: Service Unavailable, Powered by Jetty://.

The Apache Archiva service is running. No error logs are generated. 
Restarting or even reinstalling of the service has no impact.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I've found out that the jetty configuration file jetty.xml in ARCHIVA_BASE\conf got corrupted.

Solution:

1. Stop archiva service
2. Replace jetty.xml with either a fresh one or from last known working backup. A fresh copy of jetty.xml can be downloaded from [archiva web site](https://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi) as an apache-archiva-2.2.0-bin.zip. File location within the zip file is
   apache-archiva-2.2.1\conf\jetty.xml
3. Start archiva service